# re-calculate a form's output using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have constructed a form which works on values passed to it via PHP from another webpage.
Example:

```
$spa = $_POST['SpM'];
```

Then converts these values into java variables.
Example:

```
var spa = Number("<?php echo $spa; ?>");
```

Then uses these variables to add and populate new textboxes to the form.

```
function addText(count){
    $('<input type="text">').attr({'id':'d'+count, 'name':'d'+count}).val(toInch(spa+count)).prop('readonly', true).addClass("tagN").appendTo(divText);
}
```

PLEASE NOTE that the above textboxes may be any number, depending on what the COUNT variable is in the above function. For example there may be 10 fields that are generated, or about 1,000 in the extreme. This is done by using a FOR as follows:

```
for(count=1; count<max; count++){
    addText(count);
    if(count==(max-1)){break;}
}
```

I have not displayed other code that is done in the above, for greater clarity.

My question is this: all these fields display inches, and to manage that, they need to be rounded down to an understandable fraction by the user, eg. .125 for 1/8''. That's what the "toInch" function does in the above "addText" function, by using a variable "roundDown".
Now, the user has the option to change the roundDown variable to say .0625 for 1/16'', or .03125 for 1/32'' - SO: is there a quick way to re-calculate the entire form with the new rounding variable if the user decides to change it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the original value of spa+count before you use the toInch function as data.

```
function addText(count) {
    var value = spa+count;
    $('<input type="text">').attr({'id':'d'+count, 'name':'d'+count}).data("OriginalValue", value).val(toInch(value)).prop('readonly', true).addClass("tagN").appendTo(divText);
}
```

Then when the roundDown value is changed you can loop through the inputs again and recalculate the value.

```
$("input[type=text]").each(function(){
    $(this).val(toInch($(this).data("OriginalValue")));
});
```